# Openfire, LDAP and External database authentification

Tags: database, authentication, configuration, ldap, openfire

I have users on a Mysql DB and LDAP (Directory server), is it possible to connect users using both methods on Openfire server?
When I tried to connect to an external database on the profile settings, openfire gives me a choice between default or LDAP, so I chose the default and I've edited the openfire.xml and I've added properties to the ofproperty table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [custom authentication provider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/auth/AuthProvider.html) to do that.  You can probably just create a composite of the existing JDBC and LDAP providers to accomplish what you want.